# Android - Iterate all items

Tags: android, listview

after 2 hours of research i don't know what to do.

I have a listview and all elements of that listview are subviews which contain 2 elements : A textview, and a switch.

The list can be long, so i created a button to alternatively pass all the switch to yes/no.

PROBLEM : Sometimes, randomly i have 1 or 2 switchs which are not switched ...

Here's a code example of iteration :

```
for (int i = 0; i < maListViewPerso.getCount(); i++) {
    View v = maListViewPerso.getChildAt(i);
    Switch switch_temp = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.item_pers_ajout_op_switch);

    switch_temp.setChecked(tous_coches);
}
```

I try with `getCount()` instead of `getChildCount()`. Now i have the good numbers of elements in the list, but after 10 or 11 the app just crash. Because it's taking only visible elements ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: I was not able to understand the question - but whatever I understood it looks like some recycle issue is there in the listview. Could you please put more code which will make the question more clear?

Comment: you are doing it wrong. You should change the convertView inside the getView method.

Comment: I'll reply to both of you tomorrow :) i don't have time now, thx !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your adapter is based off some class, and this class has the methods to set and get the switch value, you should be able to do something like this in your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
    }
    Switch switch_temp = (Switch) v.findViewById(R.id.item_pers_ajout_op_switch);
    switch_temp.setChecked(getItem(position).getTousCoches());
    return convertView;
}

public void switchAll(boolean mySwitch) {
    for (int i=0; i<getCount(); i++) {
        getItem(i).setTousCoches(mySwitch);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I really don't have time to test your code this evening but i'll try tomorrow, thx for your answer :)

Comment: i had a big problem with my adapter.
I think i didn't understand all about arrayAdapter and i just find out a good tutorial about that. I'll give a try today and i let you know :)

Comment: Ah I see, yea tutorials really help. I hope you solve your issue

Comment: There are few things that i do not understand. I made my own class inherited from arrayAdapter.

i implemented getView. But in another method of that class, how can i get all the switchs (remind : i have a listview, each subview contains a switch). thanks :)

Comment: One way that comes to mind first is a public method that lives on the adapter that returns a list of booleans. You can follow the switchAll() method I made. Instantiate a list of Booleans, iterate through the adapter's list using a for loop and getItem, add the boolean from each switch to the list, and return the list.